# line feed character(0x0a) in html-element attribute ignored by CSS content rule

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble with line feed characters in CSS content rule.

I generate an element and assign it an attribute "text". The value of this attribute will be displayed in the elements pseudoelement `:before`
The problem is that it won't display new line characters contained in the attribute value properly. It displays them the way the are entered. I.e.: instead of a new line, I see `&#x0a` printed.

```
<div id='foo' class='somediv'>
  foo
</div>

.somediv:after {
  content: attr(text);
  white-space: pre-line;
}

document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('text', 'world &#x0a hello');
```

Fiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yp2gtc03/13/

What do I need to do for it to be displayed properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use HTML entity references in your JS. You need JS escapes. Use:

```
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('text', 'world \x0a hello');
```

```js
document.getElementById('foo').setAttribute('text', 'world \x0a hello');
```

```css
.somediv:after {
  content: attr(text);
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id='foo' class='somediv'>
  foo
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to apply `white-space: pre-line;` to the element itself, not the `:after`.

The actual text layout is part of the element.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer. I just tried it, but with no success. I updated the fiddle to reflect your suggestion. https://jsfiddle.net/yp2gtc03/18/